# How to share Github Pages via link-only option?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to share my Github Pages only via link (if possible, keeping my repo private), just like the link-only share option of Google Drive. Specifically, only those with the URL can access the github.io website that I made, while the repo (the github.com website) is preferably not accessible to anyone. May I ask if it's possible, even via third-party tools?

Answer (score 0):

if you share any link from a private repository, you will get an error 404.
Something you can do to test this behavior... is open a  chrome tab in incognito mode and paste your link ... there you will see the error.
If you want to share any link in one of your repositories, it must be Public.
If there is another possibility, please let someone tell us how to do it. regards

Answer (score 0):

In general, I don't know if there's a third-party tool to do the work, but it's easy to make it by hand, provides that you're not creating a lot of such pages.

---

First, is it possible to make a public GitHub Pages based on private repository?

Yes. Just create a private repository, head to Settings >> Options, find the section called "GitHub Pages" and set the source branch. This process is just the same as creating any GitHub pages.

P.S. you SHOULD see the message

> Caution: This repository is private but the published site will be public.

This states exactly what you want.

---

> only those with the URL can access the github.io website

Well, just make the URL difficult to guess.

For example, named the repository as a random string "uk5KKR".
However, this will likely mess up the repositories in your profile, soon after you'll be difficult to find the correct repository that you need now.
Instead, you can named name in this way: "githubpage_uk5KKR".

For other people, it's difficult to find this page when they are not provided the URL. And for you, just search "githubpage" in your profile and this repository should appear.

---

Here's a few notes:

- You should adjust the length of the random string according to how secure you need.
- It's also possible to make a quarantine area by the path name in a repository. For example, create paths "n2jnHG" and "4xSN2g" in the same repository of GitHub page, then the contents in these two paths could be shared with different people.
- Finally, note that if anyone failed to keep the URL secret, the whole page is not secret anymore. It could even become an entry in Google search result.